# How To Write Asynchronous Method in an Class Library in C#

Tags: c#, api, delegates, asynchronous

I am trying to write a class library in C#. I should use .net framework 3.0.

I have a method which converts one file type to another file type. It takes time:

```
public bool ConvertFiles()
{
    // Conversion takes a long time
    // After conversion, if conversion is successfull then I return true, 
    // else I return false
}
```

Since this method will be given to public, when API user wants to use this funtion, I should not block his application because of this method. e.g:

```
//User calls my API functions
ApiClass api = new ApiClass;
api.ConvertFiles();
// user should not wait for ConvertFiles to finish
// user's codes should continue even if ConvertFiles is not finished!
```

Therefore, I understand it, I should give API user to an "Asynchronous Method".

Until now I searched following links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14931/Asynchronous-Method-Invocation
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315582
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41777/NET-Framework-Delegates-Understanding-Asynchronou

After reading them I understand that I can create a method like this:

```
public bool ConvertFilesAsync()
{
    MethodDelegate dlgt = ConvertFiles;
    // Create the callback delegate.
    AsyncCallback cb = MyAsyncCallback;

   // Initiate the Asynchronous call passing in the callback delegate
   // and the delegate object used to initiate the call.
   IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke();
}

private void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
// Because you passed your original delegate in the asyncState parameter
// of the Begin call, you can get it back here to complete the call.
MethodDelegate dlgt = (MethodDelegate) ar.AsyncState;
// Complete the call.
bool conversion = dlgt.EndInvoke (ar) ;
}
```

When user imports my class library, he will use the function as following:

```
//User calls my API functions
ApiClass api = new ApiClass;
api.ConvertFilesAsync();
// Now user's codes continue even if ConvertFiles is not finished!
```

But how does he understand if conversion is finished with successfully? In the somewhere of his code, he should understand that file conversion is finished? How do I manage this?

Ps: I am a newbie at delegates and Asynchronous method calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Asynchronous Programming Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> The .NET Framework provides three patterns for performing asynchronous
>   operations:
>
> **Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) pattern** (also called the IAsyncResult pattern), where asynchronous operations require Begin and
>   End methods (for example, BeginWrite and EndWrite for asynchronous
>   write operations). This pattern is no longer recommended for new
>   development. For more information, see [Asynchronous Programming Model
>   (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx).
>
> **Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)**, which requires a method that has the Async suffix, and also requires one or more events, event
>   handler delegate types, and EventArg-derived types. EAP was introduced
>   in the .NET Framework 2.0. It is no longer recommended for new
>   development. For more information, see [Event-based Asynchronous
>   Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx).
>
> **Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)**, which uses a single method to represent the initiation and completion of an asynchronous
>   operation. TAP was introduced in the .NET Framework 4 and is the
>   recommended approach to asynchronous programming in the .NET
>   Framework. The async and await keywords in C# and the Async and Await
>   operators in Visual Basic Language add language support for TAP. For
>   more information, see [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since you are using .Net 3 you can use APM and EAP.

You can find an example here: [MSDN How to: Implement a Component That Supports the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (.Net 3.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hk12d4y(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `BackgroundWorker class`

You can create private field like:

```
private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
```

Then in constructor create an instance and start it running:

```
this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
this.backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
this.backgroundWorkerr.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(YourMethod);
this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

in your method you can perform sending and then add some delegates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't get it. Does this code snippet is for API? or end user will use this code snippet to run the long time running method.

Comment: It's very easy in use. Here is sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.85).aspx